# Filter special characters for AutoCompleteTextView Android

Tags: android, special-characters, autocompletetextview

I have a array of strings like :-

```
public static string[] vehicleArray = string[]{"01:00 India-Malaysia","02:00 India-Singapore","03:00 India-Malaysia"};
```

Iam passing this array to an AutocompleteTextView like so:-

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<System.String> (this, Resource.Layout.rout_row, vehicleArray);

    autoCompleteBusStop.Adapter = adapter;
```

The issue I am facing is, if I type India the items show properly, but if I enter "Malaysia" or "Singapore" the items do not show probably because "-Malaysia" is treated like one word. If i type "-" the items show. How can I search even if I type Malaysia?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom adapter for this like

```html
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


private Context context;


private List<String> originalData;
private List<String> filteredData;

private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public CustomAdapter(List<String> itemList, Context ctx) {

    originalData = new ArrayList<String>();
    filteredData = new ArrayList<String>();

    filteredData = itemList;
    originalData = itemList;

    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null);
    }

    final TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.textView);

    text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        Filter.FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            filterableString = list.get(i);

            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: It gives me an error at `results.values = nlist;` saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'Java.Lang.Object'`